# jquery plugin to integrate with database

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am useing jquery pie chart in ASP.NET. pie chart doing work properly, but I want to bind values from database. How can I do bind database values in the pie chart. I have created a table in the database and I want to fetch values from database into the pie chart.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Highcharts Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function () {
// Radialize the colors
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = $.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color)       {
return {
radialGradient: {
cx: 0.5,
cy: 0.3,
r: 0.7
},
stops: [
[0, color],
[1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
]
};
});
// Build the chart
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
{
chart:
{
renderTo: 'container',
plotBackgroundColor: null,
plotBorderWidth: null,
plotShadow: false
},
title: {
text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
},
tooltip: {
pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
percentageDecimals: 1
},
plotOptions: {
pie:
{
allowPointSelect: true,
cursor: 'pointer',
dataLabels:
{
enabled: true,
color: '#000000',
connectorColor: '#000000',
formatter: function () {
return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
}
}
}
},
series: [
{
type: 'pie',
name: 'Browser share',
data: [
['Firefox', 45.0],
['IE', 26.8],
{
name: 'Chrome',
y: 12.8,
sliced: true,
selected: true
},
['Safari', 8.5],
['Opera', 6.2],
['Others', 0.7]
]
}
]
});
});
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<di v id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Use an Ajax call to a script that fetches the database values for you. Or if it doesn't need to be asynchronous, simply fetch the database values and store them in the document, then access them with the javascript.

Comment: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871880/integrate-jquery-plugin-with-database): Two near identical questions from different people within a few minutes of each other: what's going on?