# Integrate jQuery plugin with database

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This plugin is working fine for static values. But I want to use values from database. It is a 3d chart. I have tried everything, but couldn't find any solution. So do help. I have tried various things. Searched every possible site that could explain this. But nothing has helped as of yet. Even searched about the website which makes these kind of plugins but no proper documentation was found on this. It will be of gr8 to other developers also who want to integrate any jQuery plugin with their database.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>




       <script type="text/javascript">
         var mysuperdata= null;
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: url: "Default2.aspx/GetData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { "param1": p1, "inicialDate": inicialDate, "finalDate": finalDate },
        dataType: "jsonp",
       success: function (d) { mysuperdata = d }
      });


     </script>


<script 
     type="text/javascript"                                                                                   
     src=
     "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Browser market 
                         shares at a specific website,   2010'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: 
                            <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                        percentageDecimals: 1
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                color: '#000000',
                                connectorColor: '#000000',
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + 
                                   '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                      type: 'pie',
                      name: 'Browser share',
                      data: mysuperdata
                  }]
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
     <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
           <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height:
                   400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

            </body>
          </html>       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Web;
       using System.Web.UI;
       using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
       using System.Web.Services;
       using System.Web.Script.Services;

       public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }  
         [WebMethod]
       [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
        public static Array GetData()
         {
           return new Dictionary<string, double>()
              {
                 { "Firefox", 45 },
                 { "IE", 24.8 },
                 { "Chrome", 12.8 },
                 { "Safari", 8.5 },
                 { "Opera", 5.2 },
                 { "Outros", 3.7 },
              }.ToArray();
           }
          }
```

I have edited the code adriano but still it's not working. It's showing a blank page. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871794/jquery-plugin-to-integrate-with-database): Two near identical questions from different people within a few minutes of each other: what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to explain, but here we use highcharts and load data from database.

First of all, you need to know to use jquery to send a call to a webmethod working with JSON. If you are using c# probably will be something like this:

Javascript:

```
var mysuperdata= null;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url: "Data.aspx/GetData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (d) { mysuperdata = d }
});
```

In this example you are accessing the page Data.aspx execulting the Method GetData passing no parameters. But you can pass parameters.

C#:

```
[WebMethod] 
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)] 
public static Array GetData() 
{
    return new Dictionary<string, double>()
    {
        { "Firefox", 45 },
        { "IE", 24.8 },
        { "Chrome", 12.8 },
        { "Safari", 8.5 },
        { "Opera", 5.2 },
        { "Outros", 3.7 },
    }.ToArray();
}
```

Now we know to get data! A important thing this data is your series data on chats, you send this Json:

```
        [
            ['Firefox', 45.0],
            ['IE', 26.8],
            {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            },
            ['Safari', 8.5],
            ['Opera', 6.2],
            ['Others', 0.7]
        ]
```

Your C# must return an array like this object, it's easy to mount with C#.

Finally you have your Chart:

```
     $(function () {
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market 
                     shares at a specific website,   2010'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: 
                        <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                    percentageDecimals: 1
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function () {
                                return '<b>' + this.point.name + 
                               '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: mysuperdata 
                }]
            });
        });

    });
```

Off course you can return more the 1 value, your chart is 3D, probably more complex, again this is just an explanation how you can get the data from database and insert into you chart... Please try and put you problems!

Comment: sorry adriano but i couldnt get you properly.i am quiet new to this.but still i am trying my best to understand this.it would be gr8 if only you could make it more understandable with my example

Comment: i have tried your code.but seems like im not able to understand how to do it.can u post the code of webmethod

Comment: @DividesByZero For the `WebMethod` attribute, use `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]`, or add to the top of the class file `using System.Web.Services;`.

Comment: thnx jesse.but its still showing the error in this line           [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]

Comment: What version of VS and C# are you using?

Comment: You have to add the System.Web.Script.Services;

Comment: Good! To use script method you just need the System.Web.Script.Services.

Did you advance in something?

Comment: [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public static string GetData(string param1, DateTime inicialDate, DateTime finalDate)
    {
        return(
        {
            data = new object[] { 
                new object[] { "Firefox", 45 }, 
                new object[] { "IE", 24.8 }, 
                new object[] { "Chrome", 12.8 },
                new object[] { "Safari", 8.5 }, 
                new object[] { "Opera", 5.2 }, 
                new object[] { "Outros", 3.7 } 
            }
        });
             
    }

Comment: i used this code adriano in code behind but it is showing errors.and yes i have used the namespace System.Web.Script.Services.

Comment: I've updated the code, see the GetData().
Look that the JS is changed to, I removed the parameters to the method!

Comment: adriano i also have updated the code which you told me to try.but its showing a blank page

Comment: Ow... Sorry I was on vacations hauhauhauhauhauhau 
Did you make happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to make ajax/json call you can follow my method of writing the jquery function dynamically and then registering it via startupscript. here is the code..

```
void loadchart()
{
     DateTime strat = DateTime.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
     int day = strat.Day;
     int tosub = day - 1;
     strat = strat.AddDays((0 - tosub));
     DateTime edate = strat.AddMonths(1);
     edate = edate.AddDays(-1);
     double tot = 0;
     string jq = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> $(document).ready(function () { var line1 = [";
     while (strat <= edate)
     {
          string x  = strat.ToString("dd/MMM/yy");
          double y = getregularorderamount(strat);
          tot += y;
          jq += "['"+x+"', "+y.ToString()+"],";
          strat = strat.AddDays(1);
     }
     jq = jq.Substring(0, jq.Length - 1);
     jq += @"];
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
       animate: true,";
     jq += "title: 'Total Order Amount For The Month Of - " + DateTime.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue).ToString("MMMM-yyyy") + " = &#x20B9;" + tot.ToString() + "',";
       jq += @"     axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%b&nbsp;%#d'
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                       min:0,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '&#x20B9;%.0f'
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 7.5,
                formatString: 'On date: %s, Total sale amount: %s'
            },
            cursor: {
                show: false
            }
        });
    });";
  jq+="</script>";
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "bgh", jq, false);
```

Hope this dirty method helps.

Comment: thnx ratna i will try it out

Comment: you can also use literal control instead of register.startupscript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send another AJAX request to server, and server script to get values from DB and return to your AJAX method. Then you should pass this values into your module to build diagram.

Comment: guys help me out .i started this bounty because i really need this to happen.there is so much of pressure on me to complete this.im not getting the code.because im very new.

Comment: Adriano i only have 9 hours to give my bounty of 150 points.pls answer it before that so that i can give u those points